# How to find a function who's range is an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

let $f(x)$ be defined as$$f(x)=2x-\lfloor\,sinx\rfloor$$

calculate the function $$F(x) = \int_0^x {f(t)dt}$$

at $$[0,2\pi]$$

What I did:
I first split the interval into two intervals:

- $0 \le x \le \pi $
- $\pi\le x \le 2\pi $

What I finally got is:

$$F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}{x^{2\;\;}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0 \le x \le \pi \\{x^2} - {\pi ^2} + x - \pi \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\pi  \le x \le 2\pi \end{array} \right.$$

I am not sure if I did this correctly.

**EDIT:**
I made corrections:

$$F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}{x^{2\;}} + \;{c_1}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0 \le x \le \pi \\{x^2} - x + \pi \; + {c_2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\pi  \le x \le 2\pi \end{array} \right.$$

$c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

$x=\pi$ is a common point to the two cases in the function above.
How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some errors. You have it right for $x \in [0,\pi]$. For $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$, shouldn't it be $$F(x) = \int^x_0 2t \, dt + \int^x_{\pi} (-1 ) dt = x^2 -x + \pi. $$ I'm not sure there should be $\pi^2$ and also some signs need to be flipped. Here I'm assuming that $\lfloor y \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than $y$; i.e., $y$ rounded down to the nearest integer.

Comment: Yes. I did the same way you did but I made a mistake . Thanks !
the signs are correct, I meant the floor function.
But I see that $\pi$ has two cases. should I change the function by calculate the intersection of the two conditions ?
because I need to justify why $F(x)$ is continues

Comment: @idandi An easy way to check it is if you plug in $x=\pi$ into both expressions for $F$ (on the two different regions), you should get the same answer.

Comment: I understand, Ok, thanks.

Comment: @User8128 , I think its $x^2+x-\pi$