# primitive function of f(x)

Tags: integration, continuity

Let $f(x)=2x-\lfloor \sin x \rfloor$.
I need to say if $f(x)$ has a primitive function in $[0, 2\pi]$ and to compute 
$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ in $[0,2\pi].$

Now, I think $f(x)$ has no primitive function because: $f(x)$ is bounded in $[0, 2\pi]$ and therefore integrable in $[0, 2\pi]$ and $F(x)$ is continuous. More over, $F(x)$ is differentiable  in this interval. So if $f(x)$ has a primitive function such $F(x)$, and $F'(x)=f(x)$ then $F'(\pi)=f(\pi)=2\pi$ and $F'(2\pi)=4\pi$.

According to Darboux the image of $F'(x)$ in this interval is all the numbers between $2\pi$ and $4\pi$ but there is no $x$ in this interval that make $F'(x)=f(x)=3\pi$.

What do you think? Can you help me with my other question? 
Thanks.

Comment: Functions are *differentiable* not derivable. Differentiable means "there exists a derivative" whereas derivable means "there exists a derivation"

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: I think this was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1706444/how-to-find-a-function-whos-range-is-an-integral/1706461?noredirect=1#comment3484336_1706461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I need to say if $f(x)$ has a primitive function in $[0, 2\pi]$ and to compute 
>   $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ in $[0,2\pi].$*

Since $|\sin x|\leq1$, you may just observe that, over $[0,2\pi]$, 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\pi-1,  & \text{if $x=\pi/2$} \\
3\pi+1, & \text{if $x=3\pi/2$}\\
2x, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$ Thus $f$ has a primitive over $[0,2\pi]$ which can be computed with the preceding expression.